# Django templates not altering form action

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

I have a URL file chat.urls.py:

```
`urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^message/(?P<username>\w+)/$',views.message,name='message'),
    url(r'^message/(?P<username>\w+)/submit/$',views.send_message,name='send_message'),
    url(r'^inbox/$',views.inbox,name='inbox'),
    url(r'^inbox/(?P<username>\w+)/$', views.inbox_by_user,name='inbox_by_user'),
)`
```

and a message.html template to send a message from with a form like this:

`<form action="{% url 'inbox' %}" method="post">
 {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text" value="" />
    <label for="message">Enter your message here</label><br />`

`<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>`

where I substituted previously working code for "url 'inbox'", and no matter what I substitute for the form action I always get html source rendered as

`<form action="/chat/message/[username]/" method="post"...`

no matter what. I have restarted the server, made sure I saved changes, and like it has a mind of its own, it's always `/chat/message/[username]`. When I changed that URL reverse to 'inbox' I should see chat/inbox based on the URLs.

Comment: What is the output when you type reverse('inbox') from the shell?

Comment: Hi jbiz, I get reverse('chat:inbox') --> '/chat/inbox/'

I correctly updated my template to 

`<form action="{% url 'chat:inbox' %}" method="post">`

and still getting the same `<form action="/chat/message/username/" method="post">`?!?

Comment: I tried your code, and got the expected answer, maybe you need post more code here?

Comment: So you need `{% url 'chat:inbox' %}` not `{% url 'inbox' %}`

Comment: that's no longer the issue, I just did chat:inbox and same problem. no matter what I plug in it doesn't work, and it was working a few hours ago

Comment: `Ctrl + F5` worked? just a guess

Comment: wow, my git pull; git merge chat (into master) brought in an old 'chat' templates folder where it was in an improper place during my last commit to master. it was finding an old version of the template 'message.html' which I wasn't editing. thought i was going insane, thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the information in comment, you need `{% url 'chat:inbox' %}` not `{% url 'inbox' %}` in the `form`.